# Cannot assert wildcard permission that was in contract

Tags: viper-lang

The following program fails to verify:

```
field f: Int

method m(g: Ref, i: Int)
requires acc(g.f, i * wildcard)
{
    assert acc(g.f, i * wildcard)
}
```

I first stumbled upon this where `i` was a more complex expression (specifically, an abstract function). When you turn i into a constant, it verifies. Carbon reports the error reported in https://github.com/viperproject/carbon/issues/376. I might've reported the root cause of this error once before, but I wasn't sure, so I thought I'd file an issue. Is there a chance this is a bug, or is it an (expected) incompleteness?

Adding "i > 0" as a requires clause causes the example to verify, which I don't really understand. I would either expect a well-formedness error if i needed to be bigger than 0, or a pass without the "i > 0" clause...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting example! The observed behaviour may be surprising, but can be explained. Before we go into specifics, a bit of background: when inhaling an accessibility predicate `acc(R, P)`, for some resource `R` and permission expression `p`, then `none` ≤ p is assumed. `none` is included because permission to `R` could be conditional, e.g. `requires p == (b ? write : none)`.

In your example, this yields `none ≤ i * k1`, where `k1` represents the first wildcard. For the latter, `none < k1 < write` is assumed. Observe that `i == 0` is possible, in which case `i * k1` would be `none`.

For the `assert`, a second wildcard `k2` is introduced.  Before `k2` can be assumed to be "any read fraction less than what's currently being held", i.e. before `none < k2 < perm(g.f)` can be assumed, it must be checked that `none < perm(g.f)`. This fails, however: `perm(g.f)` is `none` if `i == 0`.

Comment: Ok, so to work around this I can use: `assert perm(g.f) > 0/1 ? acc(g.f, i * wildcard) : acc(g.f, i * 0/1)`, or use permission typed parameters. Thanks.